# Help understanding a paper on quaternions by Niven and Eilenberg

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quaternions

My question is in regards to the proof of Lemma 2 in the paper "The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra" for the Quaternions, by Eilenberg and Niven.
http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1944-50-04/S0002-9904-1944-08125-1/S0002-9904-1944-08125-1.pdf

In the proof, they show that the Jacobian is non-zero for a certain map, however we are working over a non-commutative ring.  Usual determinants don't make sense over non-commutative rings, so how is it that we're able to make sense of calculating the determinant?

Comment: I just deleted a comment explaining that the determinants for quaternions do make sense - because I don't think the fact relevant here. Reading quickly through the paper, I think that  the authors are identifying the quaternions with $\mathbb R^4$, and the Jacobian is the Jacobian from cal: i.e. the $x_i$ and the $f_j$ are real. Agree?

Comment: Oh, yes of course!  Lost track there, thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure I've got this right, we're only checking that the fiber of $i$ has $n$ elements because it follows that the fiber of every element must have $n$ elements since we're dealing with a polynomial map, and that's why we declare the degree of the map is $n$?

Comment: I am afraid that I only scanned the paper - but  I think that the point was that if the jacobian does not vanish at the pre-images of $i$, then the degree is the number of pre-images. (it is not true that $0$ has $n$ distinct pre-images - but the jacobian must vanish .)

Comment: Just so you see, I just corrected/updated my previous comment -

Comment: Without looking at the paper, I'll just comment that what people may have called determinant back then is probably what we call reduced norm now.

Comment: @Kimball - that's what I too had thought at first, but no, as I wrote above, from the paper it seems like a genuine determinant = jacobian of the differentiable map $x \mapsto x^n$, where we view the quaternion $x$ as an element of $\mathbb R^4$; see my first comment.